# Parse JSON value into key-value attributes

Tags: python, json

I got the following output from my API:

```
{
'Type': 'Notification',
'MessageId': 'xxx',
'TopicArn': 'xxx',
'Subject': 'xxx',
'Message': 'EventType=Delete, FriendlyType=was deleted, '
           'Timestamp=2021-11-08T15:30:45Z, UserId=1111, UserName=me@me.com, '
           'IPAddr=(empty), AccountId=22222, AccountName=test-account, '
           'ProjectId=test-project',
'Timestamp': '2021-11-08T15:30:46.214Z',
'SignatureVersion': '1'
}
```

Now I want to access the `"Message"` variable - once I am in, and get the following output (as already visible in the previous mentioned JSON):

```
EventType=Delete, FriendlyType=was deleted, Timestamp=2021-11-08T15:30:45Z, UserId=1111, UserName=me@me.com, IPAddr=(empty), AccountId=22222, AccountName=test-account, ProjectId=test-project
```

How can I now access the keys like EventType, FriendlyType, etc.? I assume that I have to convert this output at first to a valid JSON, but I am currently baffled.

Comment: You have to _parse_ it, based on the `,` and `=` (then maybe `"2021-11-08T15:30:45Z"` -> a `datetime`, `"(empty)"` -> `None`, etc.)

Comment: No, you don't need to convert anything to JSON. You need to convert to at least a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case that you are not able to receive the Message data as a JSON, a way to handle the situation is convert the `message` string into a dict `<key>:<value>`:

```python3
message_as_dict = dict(map(lambda var: var.strip().split("=") ,message.split(",")))
```

**NOTICE** the `.strip()` in order to remove the spaces on the beginning of the key.

That shoud create a dictionary with the following structure:

```
{'EventType': 'Delete', 'FriendlyType': 'was deleted', 'Timestamp': '2021-11-08T15:30:45Z', 'UserId': '1111', 'UserName': 'me@me.com', 'IPAddr': '(empty)', 'AccountId': '22222', 'AccountName': 'test-account', 'ProjectId': 'test-project'}
```

Then you can access to the values with, for example:

```python3
print(message_as_dict["UserName"])
> me@me.com
```

---

Comment: Similarly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69886628/parse-json-value-into-key-value-attributes/69886791#comment123537597_69886791

Comment: That worked for me, great thank you very much for you help!

Comment: Hi @I13, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I did, sorry - thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

you can parse your string spliting and then use it to create a dict. Maybe it's not the best solution but it's a simple one.

```
response = {
'Type': 'Notification',
'MessageId': 'xxx',
'TopicArn': 'xxx',
'Subject': 'xxx',
'Message': 'EventType=Delete, FriendlyType=was deleted, Timestamp=2021-11-08T15:30:45Z, UserId=1111, UserName=me@me.com, IPAddr=(empty), AccountId=22222, AccountName=test-account, ProjectId=test-project',
'Timestamp': '2021-11-08T15:30:46.214Z',
'SignatureVersion': '1'
}


keyVals = [el.split('=')  for el in  response['Message'].split(', ')]

subdict = {}
for key,val in keyVals:
    subdict[key] = val
```

Comment: This makes the risky assumption that the keys and values never have `', '` or `'='` in.

Comment: I agree, but tbh this is best case parsing in a really crap scenario. Note here the following limitations: no quotes around values or keys, values may have multiple spaces, and key-values separated by a `=`, and the k-v pairs separated by a `, `. Therefore, agreed this is a risky assumption, but the data to begin with is in a weird and otherwise unsupported format, I would argue. So best outcome in a worst case scenario, would be my gut intuition here.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in one of the answer, you can parse your `Message` string, but I too feel it won't be the best solution. What I noticed is that your JSON is not in proper format. See below for proper JSON you should be getting from your API.

```
{
  "Type": "Notification",
  "MessageId": "xxx",
  "TopicArn": "xxx",
  "Subject": "xxx",
  "Message": {
    "EventType": "Delete",
    "FriendlyType": "was deleted",
    "Timestamp": "2021-11-08T15:30:45Z",
    "UserId": "1111",
    "UserName": "me@me.com",
    "IPAddr": "(empty)",
    "AccountId": "22222",
    "AccountName": "test-account",
    "ProjectId": "test-project"
  },
  "SignatureVersion": "1"
}
```

Once you are able to get this output, you may further access nested objects. For example, to access `FriendlyType` from `Message`, you can simply say, `body.Message.FriendlyType`. `body` here means your entire JSON object.

Comment: This would definitely be a better solution if the OP has (or can talk to the people with) control over the shape of the data they receive.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by splitting the `'Message'` string up into (key, value) pairs and constructing a dictionary from them:

```
from pprint import pprint

output = {'Type': 'Notification',
          'MessageId': 'xxx',
          'TopicArn': 'xxx',
          'Subject': 'xxx',
          'Message': 'EventType=Delete, FriendlyType=was deleted, '
                     'Timestamp=2021-11-08T15:30:45Z, UserId=1111, UserName=me@me.com, '
                     'IPAddr=(empty), AccountId=22222, AccountName=test-account, '
                     'ProjectId=test-project',
          'Timestamp': '2021-11-08T15:30:46.214Z',
          'SignatureVersion': '1'}

msg_dict = dict(pair.split('=') for pair in output['Message'].split(', '))
pprint(msg_dict, sort_dicts=False)
```

Output:

```
{'EventType': 'Delete',
 'FriendlyType': 'was deleted',
 'Timestamp': '2021-11-08T15:30:45Z',
 'UserId': '1111',
 'UserName': 'me@me.com',
 'IPAddr': '(empty)',
 'AccountId': '22222',
 'AccountName': 'test-account',
 'ProjectId': 'test-project'}
```